# File Manager - File Not Found - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file, ios5

This is driving me crazy...

With this simple code I keep getting file not found on my ipad device...

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
    
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    
    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: @"scoreCards.dgs" ] == YES)
        NSLog (@"File exists");
    else
        NSLog (@"File not found");
```

[image: Xcode]

**Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the resource file path using `pathForResource:ofType:` method of `NSBundle` class.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scoreCards" ofType:@"dgs"];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:path ] == YES) {}
```

Comment: But now I can't write to that file

Comment: You can't write to resource file at run time. If you want to write in a file then you first need to copy that to other directory, probably in document directory. Your resource file won't change at run time.

Comment: Its been answered in SO before but I can't find that now. You first need to copy the file from resource to document or other directory. Then application can edit and save that file. The next time you run the app you will read from document directory, not from resource again. Please Google "iOS working with file directory" for the details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your file is bundled with the app, you could use:

```
NSFileManager *filemgr;
filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"scoreCards" ofType:@"dgs"]
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: filePath ] == YES)
...
```